# Nesting windows/graphs in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, nested

Is there a way to embed a graph produced by an arbitrary plotting function in a Tkinter frame? The function mentioned below plots stuff in a separate window, I want it to plot in the same window, maybe, just nest in the master window. It seems that one might want to use `tkinter.Canvas` widget if I'm not mistaken, still in my case the graph appears in a separate window.

```
import tkinter as tk

def plot():
    #stuff for plotting
    #in this case it returns an instance of matplotlib.figure.Figure

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        self.menubar = tk.Menu()
        self.plotmenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar)
        self.plotmenu.add_command(label = "Plot", command = lambda: plot())
        self.master.config(menu = self.menubar)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label = "Plot", menu = self.plotmenu)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window = plot())

root = tk.Tk()
app = Main(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: The answer really depends on the definition of `plot`. Is that function calling some third party function that returns a image or a window object? Or, can it be modified so that you give it a reference to a canvas and it can draw directly on the canvas?

Comment: @BryanOakley, actually, it returns an instance of `matplotlib.figure.Figure`.